# PDF files to corresponding folders

Tags: merge, directory, filenames

How do I mass merge files into folders with different names?

Files:
ABCDE12568_Doe, Joseph,
Ozark_ABCDE12568_Doe, Joseph,
ABCD269543_Doe, Jane, and
DEN_ABCD269543_Doe, Jane

I need these to end up in folders like this
ABCDE12568_Doe, Joseph and
ABCD269543_Doe, Jane

While it would seem simple to create a folder and then move the files, I have the files coming from multiple sources and have literally thousands of them.  File 2 Folder creates the folders but exactly how the file is named.  I need something that will mask the files and make them match up.

Comment: You need to update us a little more on your situation. Are you programming using a certain language? Do you want to use the native services of an OS for example? and which OS?

Comment: This is a windows 10 and only really need a batch code